# Gre over IPsec Throuput performance

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, strongswan

I am testing FRR DMVPN using Strongswan IPSec + GRE. Tunnels work great and they are easily established between the branch offices. Tunnels work great and they are easily established between the branch offices. circuit. I tried to use AES-GCM encapsulation and tweak the TCP-MSS & MTU. however, I am not getting the desired results. CPU: Xeon 2nd Generation scalable. 6 cores per VM. 4 GB RAM - Ubuntu 20.04 I tried to use AES-GCM encapsulation and tweak the TCP-MSS & MTU. however, I am getting 30-50 Mb/s speed instead of 400 Mb/s which I get without IPsec. Here are my sample IPsec configs for reference

```
conn dmvpn
authby=secret
auto=add
keyexchange=ikev1
ike=aes128gcm16-aesxcbc-modp2048
esp=aes128gcm16-modp1024
dpdaction=clear
dpddelay=300s
left=%any
leftid=%any
right=%any
rightid=%any
leftprotoport=gre
rightprotoport=gre
type=transport
keyingtries=%forever
```

Would someone be able to help me with this? Let me know if I am missing anything or need more details.

Comment: "_I am not getting the desired results_" - what are the desired results? What tweaks did you try to apply, and why? What happened?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I am expecting at least 80% of my internet bandwidth as a throughput.
when I test Iperf over IPsec, I get 30-50 mbps when reaching the endpoints,
if I use Iperf without IPsec, i am getting 400 mbps.

Comment: @ChrisDavies - Done editing the question, Anything else you need input which i can clarify with ?

Comment: You've a 400 Mb/s link between the endpoints without IPsec? Degraded to about 10% through the corresponding VPN? Ouch. I know that IPsec degraded my links badly but I don't recall it being quite that much. Give me a day or two if no-one else responds and I'll see what I can find out

Comment: ok thank you @ChrisDavies